# reverse lookup multiple IP's

Tags: powershell, nslookup

If I do the below on a computer I get two IP's back. Nowthen, I want to extract both IP's and then do a reverse lookup on them - ie `"nslookup IPADDRESS"`.

How do I extract each entry and then let it do a reverse lookup on the address?

```
$computername = gc env:computername
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($computername) | select AddressList

AddressList                                                                                                                                                  
-----------                                                                                                                                                  
{10.171.80.249, 10.171.80.82}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($computername) | select -expa AddressList |
 select -expa ipaddresstostring | % { nslookup $_ }
```

Answer (score 1):

just pipe your command to the foreach-object cmdlet :

```
PS>[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($computername) | 
    select AddressList |
    foreach { 
        [System.Net.Dns]::Resolve($_.ToString()) | select hostname
    }
```

Comment: thanks for that - I forgot to mention that when I was trying I was doing a for-each but keep on failing! I see why - your one is much better and works. Thanks for that.

Comment: This doesn't work... `$_.tostring()` is empty. Return localhost